# Common word for discount and supplement

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, business-language

I need a common word that in its meaning include either *discount* or *supplement*.

Comment: What do you mean by "supplement"? And do you want a word that includes *both* meanings (as your title implies) or that includes *either* meaning (as your body text implies)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a financial context, I would use the word "Adjustment" to describe a modification of a base amount.

Comment: Use *adjust* as a verb that could mean *discount* (as a verb) or *supplement* (as a verb.)

Answer (score 1):

Incentive? Percentage? Hard to say without a bit more context.